# one substitution in Chern's intrinsic proof of Gauss-Bonnet-Chern theorem

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, curvature

In Chern's proof for Gauss-Bonnet-Chern theorem, he claims that
$$
\varepsilon_{i}u_{i_1}u_j\Omega_{ji_2}\theta_{i_3}\cdots\theta_{i_{2p-2k}}\Omega_{i_{2p-2k+1}i_{2p-2k+2}}\cdots\Omega_{i_{2p-1}i_{2p}}=P_k+2(p-k-1)\Sigma_k
$$
where
$$
P_k=\varepsilon_{i}u_{i_1}^2\Omega_{i_1i_2}\theta_{i_3}\cdots\theta_{i_{2p-2k}}\Omega_{i_{2p-2k+1}i_{2p-2k+2}}\cdots\Omega_{i_{2p-1}i_{2p}}
$$
and
$$
\Sigma_k=\varepsilon_{i}u_{i_1}u_{i_3}\Omega_{i_3i_2}\theta_{i_3}\cdots\theta_{i_{2p-2k}}\Omega_{i_{2p-2k+1}i_{2p-2k+2}}\cdots\Omega_{i_{2p-1}i_{2p}}
$$

By direct computations:

- $j=i_1$: we get $P_k$.
- $j=i_3,\dots,i_{2p-2k}$: we get $\Sigma_k$.

My question is: why
$$
\sum_{j=i_{2p-2k+1}}^{2p}\varepsilon_{i}u_{i_1}u_j\Omega_{ji_2}\theta_{i_3}\cdots\theta_{i_{2p-2k}}\Omega_{i_{2p-2k+1}i_{2p-2k+2}}\cdots\Omega_{i_{2p-1}i_{2p}}=0?
$$
It seems that
$$
\varepsilon_{i}u_{i_1}u_{j}\Omega_{ji_2}\theta_{i_3}\cdots\theta_{i_{2p-2k}}\Omega_{i_{2p-2k+1}i_{2p-2k+2}}\cdots\Omega_{i_{2p-1}i_{2p}}\\=\varepsilon_{i}u_{i_1}u_{i_{2p-2k+1}}\Omega_{i_{2p-2k+1}i_2}\theta_{i_3}\cdots\theta_{i_{2p-2k}}\Omega_{i_{2p-2k+1}i_{2p-2k+2}}\cdots\Omega_{i_{2p-1}i_{2p}}
$$
for all $j\in\{2p-2k+2,\dots,2p\}$, then why
$$
\varepsilon_{i}u_{i_1}u_{i_{2p-2k+1}}\Omega_{i_{2p-2k+1}i_2}\theta_{i_3}\cdots\theta_{i_{2p-2k}}\Omega_{i_{2p-2k+1}i_{2p-2k+2}}\cdots\Omega_{i_{2p-1}i_{2p}}=0?
$$

Any help would be appreciated.

The link for Chern's original proof is:
[https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/chern7.pdf](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/%7Ev1ranick/papers/chern7.pdf)

Comment: Now that I've removed all the ridiculous spaces which made this unreadable ... Where precisely does Chern claim this equation? I cannot find what you've typed in the paper.

Comment: @TedShifrin: Thanks for your comments. I think Chern claims this equation on P751: "The expression (18) for d\Phi_k then becomes..."

Comment: OK, I see what you are referring to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's all that is going on. It is the skew symmetry in the $\epsilon_i$ symbol. Because $\theta_{i_3}\wedge\dots\wedge\theta_{i_{2p-2k}}$ is a form of even degree, we have for $\mu$ odd in $2p-2k+1,\dots,2p-1,2p$,
$$\Omega_{i_\mu i_2}\wedge (\dots) \wedge \Omega_{i_\mu i_{\mu+1}} = \Omega_{i_\mu i_{\mu+1}}\wedge (\dots) \wedge \Omega_{i_\mu i_2},$$
but switching $2$ and $\mu+1$ introduces a factor of $-1$ in the $\epsilon_i$. Thus, the sum (for $j=i_\mu$ fixed) is zero.
And if $\mu$ is even, first write $\Omega_{i_\mu i_2}=-\Omega_{i_2i_\mu}$ and make the same argument with $2$ and $\mu-1$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I should make a full use of the skew-symmetry of the symbol...